# Spring batch RowMapper - get number of columns and type

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my batch job application, I am using

```
org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader
```

The SQL query is not known at compile time.

I am having trouble with `RowMapper` interface and its

```
T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException;
```

Having only the resultset I can't know the number of columns and type of each column.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `rs.getMetaData()`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html